# How to get xpath to a link to picture?

Tags: image, parsing, xpath

How to extract xpath to link of image? I want to extract this specific link:

```
http://insales.ru/images/bigpic.jpeg
```

I dont know how I must specify xpath. Do I have to include all parent  tags to get it or I just can go directly to  tag?

```
<div class="tango">
<div class="container-horizontal">
     <div class="clip-horizontal">
        <ul id="carousel" class="pagination jcarousel">
             <li class="jcarousel-item">
                 <a rev=http://insales.ru/images/bigpic.jpeg href="http://insales.ru/images/pic2.jpeg">
                   <img src="http://insales.ru/images/thumb.jpeg">
                 </a>
             </li>          
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So my xpath would be:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarouse')]/a
```

Or I have to include all parent div tags:

```
//div[@class="tango"]//div[@class="container-horizontal"]//li[contains(@class, 'jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarouse')]/a
```

But anyway both of this xpaths don't work.

How to specify xpath to extract this link: http://insales.ru/images/bigpic.jpeg

Comment: I get a `404` on http://insales.ru/images/bigpic.jpeg

Comment: Actually names and links are a bit different, They are much longer. So i put some fake short links to better understand code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options but the shortest one is probably:

```
.//*[@id='carousel']/li/a/img
```

Comment: Seems to be working. But can you please explain. Why you left all div tags? So I dont need to include all parent tags in xpath? And is it possible for example in xpath you specified make some changes. For example li[@class="jcarousel-item"]/a/img